# Structural Search for log.debug(String.format.... not working as expected

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

I'm doing a search for the following

```
$Instance$.debug(String.format($Parameter$))
```

and found lots of instances from before we have a sensible logging framework in our project, however some calls are not being found and I don't understand what the difference is with those vs the ones that did get found. This didn't get found:

```
log.debug(
    String.format(
        "Failed to discard amendment (%s)", amendmentToDiscard.getID()),
    amendment_.getFields());
```

[image]

Comment: The reason that my search didn't find the result I listed is that I hadn't noticed that there was a second argument to the method `log.debug` and my search was only looking for multiple parameters to the `String.format` method but a single param to log.debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following template `$Instance$.$MethodCall$($Parameter$)`:

[image]

Comment: The screenshot shows structural search with the template `$Instance$.$MethodCall$($Parameter$)` and a filter on `$MethodCall$` of the type `Text` with a value of `debug`.